# AngularJS templates can't use JSON that contains hyphen

Tags: angularjs

AngularJS templates can't use JSON that contains hyphen in the key.

e.g.

My Json looks like

```
{
   ...
   link: {
       xx-test:{
            href: '/test/xx'
         }
}
```

Now, in my angularjs template if I refer the href it is not working

```
<a ng-href="/app/edit?item={{item.link.xx-test.href}}"></a>
```

It is unable to resolve the value  href is rendered as 
/app/edit?item=

It tried

```
<a ng-href="/app/edit?item={{'item.link.xx-test.href'}}"></a>
<a ng-href="/app/edit?item={{item.link.xx\-test.href}}"></a>
<a ng-href="/app/edit?item={{item.['link.xx-test'].href}}"></a>
```

Comment: not sure where your "json" (which is not json , it is a javascript object, json is a textual representation of that object) comes from but it is not a valid javascript object if your keys are not quoted if they contain non valid variable characters. If you quote the keys correctly , item.link["xx-test"].href should work.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The object key needs to be quoted with:

```
$scope.bar = {'xx-test':'foo'};
```

Bracket notation should be used in the angular expression.

```
<p>{{bar['xx-test']}}</p>
```

You can optionally escape the hyphen `\-` in the angular expression.

Comment: so, is this a limitation due to angular or should hyphens not be used in key names?  if the former, is it because of the translation angular does between hyphenated names in the DOM and it's camelcase counterpart in Javascript (i.e. <my-directive/> --> myDirective)?

Comment: It's because hyphens are interpreted as minuses

Answer (score 2):

try {{item.link['xx-test'].href}}

For further reading on bracket notation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects