# ng view is not working but ng include work in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, routes, mean-stack

Can someone please help me, i don't know what am i doing wrong. I am following mean web development tutorial. Ng-include works ok with templates, but ng-view not. I have 5 files. First is Users.client.module.js:

```
angular.module('users', []);
```

Second is users.client.controller.js

```
    angular.module('users',['ngRoute']).controller('UsersController', ['$scope', 
function ($scope){
    $scope.name = 'UsersCont';
    console.log("from UsersCont");
}]);
```

Third is users.client.routes.js

```
angular.module('users').config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'users/views/register-user.client.view.html'

    })
    .otherwise({
        templateUrl: '/somewhere else'
    });
}]);
```

Fourth is register-client-view.html

```
<section ng-controller="UsersController">
    <h1>{{ name }}</h1>
</section>
```

and last is index.html

```
<section ng-include=" 'users/views/register-user.client.view.html' "></section>

<section ng-view> </section>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/users/users.client.module.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/users/controllers/users.client.controller.js"></script>
```

Please help

Comment: I don't see `ng-app` anywhere in your index.html  It is required for bootstraping the ng applicaiton. Also this seems weird `ng-include=" 'users/views/register-user.client.view.html' "` - why do you have additional quotes inside?

Comment: i have file for manually bootstrapping application.js 
var mainApplicationModuleName = 'myApp';
var mainApplicationModule = angular.module(mainApplicationModuleName, ['ngResource' ,'ngRoute', 'users', 'articles']); 
mainApplicationModule.config(['$locationProvider', function ($locationProvider){
 $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
}]);

angular.element(document).ready(function(){
 angular.bootstrap(document, [mainApplicationModuleName]);
}); ng-include works fine, i tried without single quote's but not working. i think problem is somewhere with routes but i can't find it.also tried with ng-app

Comment: I don't see you loading `users.client.routes.js` in your index. Do you have this?

Comment: omg..thank you 1000 times Devin H. i didn't had included users.client.rotues.js...

Answer (score 1):

You have to use ngRoute as a dependency for that

Try the following code

```
var app = angular.module('users', ['ngRoute']);
```

And also dont forget to include the angular route js file just after angular main js file.

```
<script src="Scripts/Vendors/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you for quick response Hasib Hasan Arnab, i have tried before i asked question with ['ngRoute'] in my module.js file, but also didn't work. i already have included angular-route.js after angular.js, now i tried with minified version and still won't work...really don't know what to do...once again thank you for helping me

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the problem is caused by hyphen in name of template.
See this answer [AngularJS templates can't use JSON that contains hyphen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582367/angularjs-templates-cant-use-json-that-contains-hyphen)

Try either renaming the template name (replace hyphen with underscore) or escape it with backslash.

I guess that hyphen in considered as minus sign and angular (or javascript) is then confused by it. That's also reason why this works `ng-include=" 'users/views/register-user.client.view.html' "` and this does not work `ng-include="users/views/register-user.client.view.html"`

Comment: thank you for helping, that is why are single quotes. but i think this is not the problem. i have also in articles routes articles/views/list-articles.client.view.html and works fine when route is '/articles'...i think problem is with routing any template i put ng-view doesn't show. i will start over again and try to find mistake...right now i don't have idea...